# nested ng-repeat, radio button validate

Tags: angularjs

I have two nested ng-repeat that generate multiples questions and each question contain a bunch of radio buttons. I'm having trouble coming up with a efficient way to display the validation error message when no radio is selected for a certain question, and get all the selected choices when user hit select

```
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="question in questionModel.questionaire">{{question.question}}
      <span style = "color:red" ng-show = "!!!ANOTHER CONDITION HERE!!! && questionModel.submitClicked != false">Please choose an answer </span>

          <ul>

            <li ng-repeat="answer in question.answers">
              <input  type="radio"
                      ng-click="questionModel.handleChange(answer)"
                      value={{answer}}
                      name="radio_{{$parent.$index}}"
                      required>
              {{answer}}
            </li>
          </ul>

      </li>
    </ul>
```

How do you suggest I approach this? Use getElementById on `ul` then check all the children node? that sound really messy though, but it is easy, I can easily get all the button that was checked. Is there a better way to approach this for the validation error message?

If all radio buttons were under same question that would be easy, I can just ng-model on the radio button.

edit: addition info

controller:

```
  myApp.controller('questionController', function($scope, $http, toServer){

    $scope.questionModel = {
      questionaire: [],
      submitClicked: false,

      handleChange: function(ans){
        console.log(ans);
      },

      submit: function(){
        this.submitClicked = true;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.questionaire));
      }
    }

    toServer.get_All_Questions(function(response){
      $scope.questionModel.questionaire = response;
    });

  })
```

a service I created for ajax call:

```
//this service handle all the ajax call to server
myApp.factory('toServer', function($http){

  return {

    get_All_Questions: function(callback){
      var url = "/health1/server/questions";

      $http.get(url).success(function(response){
        response.forEach(function(item){
          item.answers = (item.answers != null) ? item.answers.split(",") : [];
          item.answered = false;
        });
        callback(response);
      }).error(function(response){
        console.log("error " + response)
      });
    }

  }

});
```

structure of the $scope.questionModel.questionaire (the response from server) is an array of json:

```
[{id: "1", question: "what's your name?", answers: ["tom", "mary"]},
{id: "2", question: "what's your age?", answers: [1, 2]}
]
```

Comment: `!!question.answered` ?

Comment: o that's just a variable, I was playing around with it hoping to come up with a solution

Comment: @LoremIpsum What `questionModel.handleChange()` does?

Comment: another pointless function. All it does is it print out the argument that got passed into handlechange with `console.log`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was no property to recognize whether the question has been answered. So, i took the effort of creating such a property as `isAnswered = true/false` and initialized it to false on default.

```
angular.forEach($scope.questionModel.questionaire, function(ques) {
    ques.isAnswered = false;
    return ques;
});
```

When an answer is selected, the function `handleChange` sets `isAnswered = true`.

```
handleChange: function(ans, ques){
    ques.isAnswered = true;
    console.log(ques);
},
```

Finally, On submit click, the condition checks whether submit is clicked and if any question is unanswered, it will show the following message:

```
<span style = "color:red" 
   ng-show = "questionModel.submitClicked && !question.isAnswered">
   Please choose an answer 
</span>
```

[Working Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/lRde5GzWOtjpMb4TqFAA?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

It's easy – use `ng-model` for your radio buttons:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="question in questionModel.questionaire" {{question.question}}
  <span style = "color:red" ng-show="!question.selectedAnswer && questionModel.submitClicked">Please choose an answer</span>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="answer in question.answers">
          <input  type="radio"
                  ng-model="question.selectedAnswer"
                  ng-click="questionModel.handleChange(answer)"
                  value={{answer}}
                  name="radio_{{$parent.$index}}">
          {{answer}}
        </li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hey yea the ng-model is causing me a problem. Now all the radio buttons in different questions are 'linked' when I click a radio button in question 1, then click a radio button in question 2, question1's radio button selecteion is cleared. Which is weird cause they are under different name

Comment: @user308553 Show me the how `questionModel.questionaire` generating and how the frontend is looking. So I can imagine what is the problem.

Comment: I added in some additional code in original post, thanks

Comment: I also added a sample of the data structure received from server

Comment: @user308553 Thanks, taking a look now

Comment: @user308553 On page you have all questions listed and Submit button below?

Comment: yeah, all question and the asscoiated radio button (choices). Then a submit button

Comment: @user308553 Do you want to skype, I'm very interesting to help you :) But it's difficult to understand the problem why ng-model doesn't work properly without working code?

Comment: Hey i would love to but my mic is not working. I know why ng-model wont work. `Cause ng-model linked to value`. What happens is all the button are binded to `question.selectedAnswer`. So when you select a button (say the value of chosen button is 'tom' under question "what is your name?"). Now if you go and select another button in the second question (e.g. 'what is your age', you pick '23'). What happen is first question is binded to the same `question.selectedAnswer` which is now set to '23', but in question 1 there is no such choice, so question 1 selection is gone. Does that make sense?

Comment: @user308553 Nope. It should work, because it's named the same `question.selectedAnswer`, but in run-time it is different questions. Maybe teamviver? You mic won't be needed, but can play around with the code?

Comment: no I'm sure  selectedAnswer is linked to value is causing this problem. Because I've just made two extra questions with same choices. When you select a choice of first question, second question automatically select the same choice too. All set of buttons' value are binded to selectedAnswer, one change to a button cause all other button's value change to that too, and if those set of buttons doesn't contain a value of selectedAnswer nothing will get selected of that set

Comment: Hey Max anyways thanks for the help! some guy posted a solution by adding an extra key to the JSON, I think I will just use that. Thank you so much for helping